# copy-paste listview item using drag-drop

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, copy-paste, listviewitem

I have loaded some images in a listview using imagelist in c#. Now I want to copy any image and paste into another image within this listview using drag and drop. that is copy first image and paste into second image in the same listview. How could I do this? sample code would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to change the image of the listviewitem that you dropped another listviewItem into?